# Adding a callback to a Redux Reducer

Tags: reactjs, callback, redux

Would there be anything wrong/anti-pattern-ish (in terms of '*thinking-in-react/redux*') in added a callback to the `action.data` passed into an action?

```
// reducer
ACTION_FOR_REDUCER() {
  var x = 123
  if ( action.data.callback ) action.data.callback( x )
  return {
    something: action.data.somedata
  }
},
```

Then accessing that data later in the App when the action is called (in an container perhaps)

```
// later in the app
this.props.dispatch(changeSomething({
  somedata: somedata,
  callback: (x) => { console.log(x) }
}))
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The idea is not wrong, the implementation is.

Instead of adding a callback, return a promise from the action (you will need [redux-thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk) middleware or some similar alternative).

Then you can simply do:

```
dispatch(myAction).then(callback);
```

Of course, you can also simply dispatch another action in your callback, which usually end up being one compound action.

```
const myAction = ...
const callbackAction = ...

const compoundAction = () => dispatch => {
     dispatch(myAction())
         .then(() => dispatch(callbackAction()));
};
```

Answer (score 8):

The third principle of Redux (listed in the [introduction section of the docs](http://redux.js.org/docs/introduction/ThreePrinciples.html#changes-are-made-with-pure-functions)) is that **'changes are made with pure functions'**.

A pure function is a function that always returns the same result given the same inputs, and doesn't cause any side effects. Having a callback log something out most definitely would be a side effect!

[The docs go on to say:](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Reducers.html#handling-actions)

> It's very important that the reducer stays pure. Things you should never do inside a reducer:
>
> - Mutate its arguments;
> - Perform side effects like API calls and routing transitions;
> - Call non-pure functions, e.g. Date.now() or Math.random().

The reasoning behind this is it makes your reducers predictable - you know that, given an action with a certain payload, you're *guaranteed* to have the same output. This makes your app both easier to understand as a developer, and easier to unit test.

If you want to perform side effects when an action takes place, you should install a middleware that allows you to do so - some common examples of these are:

- [redux-thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk), which allows you to dispatch functions that can in turn dispatch actions (commonly used to make API calls)
- [redux-logger](https://github.com/evgenyrodionov/redux-logger), which allows you to log out actions that are dispatched.
- [redux-devtools-extension](https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension), which allows you to view your state and actions in a Chrome devtools extension.

If you can't find a middleware package that does what you need (rare, to be honest - there's lots out there already!), you can [write your own](http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/Middleware.html) quite easily.

Comment: If you want call some external APIs, I would suggest to create your own `middleware`

Comment: @Ematipico: Will add some details on middleware to the answer :)

Comment: Thanks, I think redux-thunk is what i'm looking for. On the subject of mutation though, isn't the mutation happening later as part of the `dispatch`, and not in the reducer itself?

Answer (score 0):

Callbacks introduce side-effects, so when using Redux you should consider returning a new state with the result, for example with `done: true` flag and react to that in `componentDidUpdate`.

For managing asynchrony and effects you can use [redux-saga](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga), [redux-thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk), [RxJs](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS) or another library.
If you want to stick with callbacks, why even bother with Redux?